# Angular js make slider with infinite effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I created a simple photo slider but i does not how to make this infinite. 
How can i make this effect with the angular way, please help.
I does not want to use jquery, but if it is the only way so whatever.

```js
var app = angular.module('stack', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = ["http://lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/", "http://lorempixel.com/600/200/city/",
    "http://lorempixel.com/600/200/nature/"
  ];
  $scope.index = 0;
  var IMG_WIDTH = -600;
  $scope.next = function() {

    ++$scope.index;
    if ($scope.images.length <= $scope.index) {
      $scope.index = 0;
    }

    var pos = ($scope.index > 0) ? $scope.index * IMG_WIDTH : 0;

    $scope.listPosition = {
      transform: "translateX(" + pos + "px)"
    };

  }

  $scope.prev = function() {
    --$scope.index;
    if ($scope.index < 0) {
      $scope.index = $scope.images.length - 1;
    }

    var pos = ($scope.index > 0) ? $scope.index * IMG_WIDTH : 0;

    $scope.listPosition = {
      transform: "translateX(" + pos + "px)"
    };

  }
});
```

```css
.mt {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.outer {
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
  width: 90000px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.slider div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<body ng-app="stack" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3">
        <div class="outer clearfix">
          <div class="slider clearfix" ng-style="listPosition">
            <div ng-repeat="image in images track by $index">
              <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="next()">Next</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="prev()">Prev</a>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to shuffle `$scope.images` array.

- Once transition has been done, disable them, either by creating something like `.no-transition` class and adding it to the slider or by any other way you can imagine
- `$scope.images.push($scope.images.shift())` should put first item to last position, `$scope.images.unshift($scope.images.pop())` should reverse it.
- After that, you'll probably have to re-adjust transform value and re-apply transitions

Hope that helps.

Comment: But which phase i do this stuff? i really appreciate an example i am lost.

Comment: I don't have time for a full example, but it you should put above snippets in `$scope.next` and `$scope.prev`, respectively. Try putting only those two (without the rest of the code) and see what happens, it will be much more clear. If you can't figure it out, leave a comment and I'll make short examplem but I doubt it will be necessary :)

Comment: I can not make it work, i update the plunker please have a look, http://plnkr.co/edit/irF7jMIQvb0dtcyxpF4I?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/qWsQHMp3VpdKWcu2YoEA?p=preview this will, hopefully illustrate what I had in mind, and I think it's a really simple solution. This way, only first slide in $images array is visible and you have much less calculation of position, because it can offset one slide left or right. I'd make that work all the way, but currently I'm short on time, sorry for that

Comment: I will mark this as answer but i does not success to add the transition.

Comment: $scope.listPosition = {
        transform: "translateX(" + IMG_WIDTH + "px)"
      };
      $timeout(function() {
         $scope.images.push($scope.images.shift());
      },1000)
after the transition it is jump to slide 3